# Can't SSH to server with VPN connection

Tags: networking, server, ssh, dns, vpn

This is quite messed up, I know. Let me explain it all.

I have a dynamic DNS set on my router. I verified that, after port forwarding, I can connect to desired application (if I run something on port 1337 and forward the port to appropriate machine I can connect to it from outside with no issues).

Now, if I connect my Macbook to VPN and run something as described above, it works as expected. **BUT**, if I connect my machine running Ubuntu Server 16.04 to the VPN and run something or want to connect by ssh, it fails. I forwarded port I'm using for SSH connection on router. I also tried hosting a web server, which also failed.

What can I do about this issue? This doesn't make sense to me.

About Ubuntu Server machine: it's a clean install with openvpn client and ssh server configured, no firewall running, iptables not edited, connected to router via ethernet.

EDIT: Here are the routing tables:
 http://pastebin.com/ay6fpLcL

Comment: What are the differences in the routing tables with and without the VPN (for IPv4 only, `ip -4 r` on ubuntu, `netstat -f inet -rn` on mac) ?

Comment: @user4556274 here are the tables: http://pastebin.com/ay6fpLcL

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, I managed to find a solution.

## Using `openvpn` package without any wrappers:

Add those 2 lines to your `.ovpn` file (or `.conf` if you're auto connecting):

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/up.sh
```

Then, create `/etc/openvpn/up.sh` with executable permissions (755/700):

```
#!/bin/sh
ip rule add from <your-server-ip> table 128
ip route add table 128 to <your-server-subnet> dev <your-interface>
ip route add table 128 default via <server-gateway>
```

For example, here's my configuration:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip rule add from 192.168.1.26 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.1.1
```

## Using a different VPN client/different configuration:

I can't predict the steps required, but generally you need to run `up.sh` script (above) everytime your VPN connection is established.

Hope it helps someone having the same issue. Cheers!

Comment: I use NordVPN on ubuntu 18.04. Using openvpn preceeded by this script works fine. However, using the nordvpn binary to connect fails with the above.